# Вывод элементов списка по одному в строке (в столбик)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как можно вывести список не в строку, а в столбик?
Допустим у нас есть список.

```
list = ['1', '2', '3']
```

А в коде программы есть место, где этот список должен выводиться в окно GUI в виде лэйбла после нажатия кнопки.

```
lbl = Label(master, text=list)
lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Я пробовал добавить в список (после каждого элемента списка) '\n' и вроде бы даже получилось, но вместе с элементами списка так же распечатываются фигурные скобки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно избавиться от фигурных скобок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно привести все элементы списка к строкам, объединить все в одну строку с помощью метода `join`, потом уже выводить в `Label`:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

lst = ['1', '2', '3']
text = "\n".join(map(str, lst))
# или text = "\n".join(str(item) for item in lst)
lbl = tk.Label(master, text=text)
lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

Если в исходном списке уже строки, а не числа или другие типы объектов, то можно сразу делать `join`:

```
lst = ['07:59', '08:00', '08:49']
text = "\n".join(lst)
lbl = tk.Label(master, text=text)
```

Comment: Да, у меня как раз в оригинале в списке время :) Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы можно добавить перед выводом *:

```
    list = [1, 2, 3]
    print(*list)
```

Comment: Это работает с print, а у меня вывод в окно GUI через text. Но тем не менее, спасибо за идею )